# timeout event design with a detached thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer

I have a linked list, and I insert nodes into it frequently.

for each node, after it is inserted, an element inside the node needs to be updated in 5 seconds, if no updating happends inside the 5 seconds, the node needs to be deleted.

my current design is to fire a detached thread, the routine is:

```
func{
   sleep(5);
   flag=check_updating(node);
   if(flag == false)
      delete(node);       
}
```

is this design OK or not?

are there better designs?
thanks!

Comment: That design is not OK without mutex-protection of the nodes and/or list, no. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using threads is a pretty heavy way of dealing with timers, but if you're not too concerned with performance I suppose it'll work just fine.

I would say use something like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and queue your timers up in those systems. They'll be able to handle your timing needs without breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big the list can be. If you insert nodes very fast, creating and destroying threads will be slow, and may even reach the system maximum number of threads.